# Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.storage'

Tags: python, linux, azure, import, azure-storage

I have created python function to deploy onto azure function app. It runs successfully on my local machine, and successfully getting deployed onto the azure function app also. However, when I test it on my subscription, it is throwing Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.storage' error. and is pointing to a line in my python file 'import azure.storage'.

EDIT: "since i changed the sequence of import modules, now the error is on appendserviceblob from azure-blob-storage"

Details:

1. I am using python 3.9 version and so is my functon app of linux OS.
2. My requirements.txt contains:
   azure-core
   azure-functions
   azure-storage
   azure-storage-blob

Please if someone can give a feedback.

I tried to amend my requirements.txt file but no luck.
Attaching photos:

[requirement.tc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmjyK.png)

[modules imported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIzkX.png)

[azure function error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ozolb.png)

Comment: How are you building you function app and deploying it?

Comment: I tried both methods of creating function app (azure UI and VScode). I have also deployed the function app via cmd and VScode as well. I ASSUMED that --build-native-deps would anyway resolve my issue but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that azure-storage is deprecated?

[image: pip fails to install azure-storage]

raw output:

```
pip install azure-storage
Collecting azure-storage
  Using cached azure-storage-0.37.0.zip (4.3 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-b5bzzs55/azure-storage_4db88e4fc79d49348bcbaf111e82d894/setup.py", line 55, in <module>
          raise RuntimeError(message)
      RuntimeError:
      
      Starting with v0.37.0, the 'azure-storage' meta-package is deprecated and cannot be installed anymore.
      Please install the service specific packages prefixed by `azure` needed for your application.
      
      The complete list of available packages can be found at:
      https://aka.ms/azsdk/python/all
      
      Here's a non-exhaustive list of common packages:
      
      - [azure-storage-blob](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob) : Blob storage client
      - [azure-storage-file-share](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-file-share) : Storage file share client
      - [azure-storage-file-datalake](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-file-datalake) : ADLS Gen2 client
      - [azure-storage-queue](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-queue): Queue storage client
      
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.0
[notice] To update, run: python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

It might be that because of this your azure function refuses to install the dependencies.

[Here you can find the Azure python sdk and currently supported packages.](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/releases/latest/all/python.html)

Kind regards

Comment: I checked the current status of azure-storage on the given linked by you. It does shows me azure-storage module in a beta version.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately the link of the beta version offers the same information (that it is deprecated) -  [as shown here](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage/0.37.0/).

Comment: I understand. Does that mean anything related to azure-storage module wont work now? or is it that a partiuclar version is deprecated?

Comment: Also, how it running locally on my machine when the package is seems to be deprecated? I am confused.